# List of online users using membership asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I want to have a list that contains online users in my web site i use this code in local host but it did't shows me any user. Can any body help me? where did i make mistake?

```
  MembershipUserCollection users;


        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Bind users to ListBox.
            List<MembershipUser> onlineUsers = new List<MembershipUser>();
            foreach (MembershipUser user in Membership.GetAllUsers())
            {

                if (user.IsOnline)
                {
                    onlineUsers.Add(user);

                }

            }
            ListBox1.DataSource = users;
            ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I write it in my page load.

Comment: Yes i test it with 2 browser, but not at the internet. I did it at local host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = users;
```

To this:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = onlineUsers;
```

Also do not forget to set the DataKeyField and DataValueField properties on the ListBox1.

Comment: Thanks Funny mistake!! it works, but it shows me some offline users!! that's strange!

Comment: No problem, glad to help - the "offline" users issue might be session timeout related - i.e. even though the user has closed the browser the session has not yet timed out and therefore is still showing them as "online". Oh don't forget to mark this question as complete (and vote up my answer if you are able!).

Comment: How can can i remove this problem. Do you have any idea?

Comment: AFAIK there is no "clean" way to do this - search stack for "ASP.NET Force logout" and you'll get a mix of results some of which might be suitable.

Comment: Where do I write this if am using asp.net MVC?

Comment: @Dayakar see this link for MVC style solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774347/get-a-list-of-online-users-in-asp-net-mvc