# Get all ONLINE users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

Is there a way to get all ONLINE (logged in) users in asp.net core 3.1

I didn't find anything that solves my problem on the internet.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello! Does a list of active sessions help you?

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774347/get-a-list-of-online-users-in-asp-net-mvc). You can also implement SignalR to keep list of online users.

Answer (score 0):

You should add some static collection to your Startup class and add user there when he is logged in and remove it when the user is logged out.

More details refer this: [How Get logged in users list (online users) in Asp.Net Core 1](https://forums.asp.net/t/2113601.aspx?How+Get+logged+in+users+list+online+users+in+Asp+Net+Core+1+)

Comment: Look how ugly that bare link is.  FTFY.